# Is there a way to make VSCode move to the start of the code (not the start of the line itself)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I have CTRL-A bound to "cursorLineStart", but that brings me to the far left of the buffer, generally a multiple levels of indent before the code starts. Is there a way to make CTRL-A go to the start of the code itself, maybe "first word" or something similar? Thanks!

Edit: Trying to be more clear. I already have a key bound for "Go to beginning of line" ("cursorLineStart"), what I'm trying to do is intelligently go to the start of the code on that line instead of going to the very beginning and having to move over several levels of indent. So go to first non-whitespace on a line.

Answer (score 2):

You can view keybinds within VSCode by opening the command palette (CMD + SHIFT + P on a Mac) -> "Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts". The search on this settings page is really good.

The behavior you are looking for `cursorHome` I believe? You can rebind anything here.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows (not specific to VSCode): `Ctrl+Home` to go to home and `Ctrl+End` to go to the end.